Searching for vintage piece
I'm trying to repair my vintage gazelle impala bike and I'm missing just one piece :( Does anyone know where I can find the piece seen in the photo? It's part of the brake cable anchor bolt.
Thank you!!


You should check out the local bike shops which sells or repairs vintage bikes.

A quick google of "gazelle impala" indicates that there have been a variety of types with different brakes. A picture of the brake will improve the chances of identifying the part.
